# ReactJS - Waiting for user to finish multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, event-handling, event-listener

I just started learning ReactJS so any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to make a form where user inputs his/her address into multiple input fields. When the user finishes typing into ALL input fields, then a function will be triggered to validate the address. Through research, I found out about onChange and onBlur but it seems like that only works for one input field. Is there any other way to keep track of all five inputs and trigger a function after the user finishes? Or if there is any way to use onChange to do so, I would love to know. The following is the code for my form. Thank you in advance.

```
<form>
      <label>
        <DebounceInput
          name="addressLine1"
          placeholder="Address Line 1"
          debounceTimeout={300}
          onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, name)}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <DebounceInput
          name="addressLine2"
          placeholder="Address Line 2"
          debounceTimeout={300}
          onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, name)}
          value={this.state.address.addressLine2}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <DebounceInput
          name="city"
          placeholder="City"
          debounceTimeout={300}
          onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, name)}
          value={this.state.address.city}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <br />
        <DebounceInput
          name="state"
          placeholder="State"
          debounceTimeout={300}
          onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, name)}
          value={this.state.address.state}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <DebounceInput
          name="postalCode"
          placeholder="Postal Code"
          debounceTimeout={300}
          onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, name)}
          value={this.state.address.postalCode}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
```

Comment: Actually validation doesn't work like this anymore. It has to be dynamic. Use redux-form instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can incorporate a condition inside of your handleChange function, where you check if your currentstate is sufficient to do a validation, if so you can trigger the validation.